# How to copy specific file from one directory to another directory in same repository in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, repository

I am moving specific file (e.g. 5 json file) from one directory to another directory in same repository. I was able to extract the file and published to Devops successfully, but those specific file didn't upload to main root directory of Azure Devops where all other files are present.

Steps performed-

1. Download specific file from old repository as a zip folder on local machine.
2. Then upload the same zip file to new Azure Devops repository where I want to copy those file. [image]PFA,Screenshot 1.
3. Created a pipeline which includes the following task activity:

   - Used the extract Files in built task and used the same zip file in archive file pattern and destination folder - $(BuildSourceDirectory)
   - Copy all the extracted files from $(BuildSourceDirectory) to $(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory).
   - Publish artifacts from $(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory) to 'azure pipeline' artifact publish location.
     Till this point, artifact has been generated and published successfully and I can see specific file extracted there (e.g. 5 file). PFA, Screenshot 2.[image]

PFA, Screenshot 3 where I want to copy a specific file.[image]

source (zip file)= main root directory of Azure Devops Repository XX

Target = main root directory of Azure Devops Repository XX

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below YAML will help you move the .json files in Azure Git repository:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
variables:
- name: system.debug
  value: true
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #cut json files from dir1 to dir2
      
      import os
      import shutil
      
      sourcefolder = "./dir1"
      targetfolder = "./dir2"
      
      def move_json_file_fromxtox(sourcefolder, targetfolder):
          try:
              for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sourcefolder):
                  for file in files:
                      if file.endswith(".json"):
                          shutil.move(os.path.join(root, file), targetfolder)
          except Exception as e:
              print(e)
      
      move_json_file_fromxtox(sourcefolder, targetfolder)

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git config --global user.email "<email address here>"
      git config --global user.name "<user name here>"
      git add .
      git commit -m 1
      git push origin HEAD:main
```

You need these settings before run the pipeline:

[image]

[image]

This is my original repository structure:

[image]

After run the above pipeline, those files will be moved successfully, the repository structure will be:

[image]