# Create Azure Pipeline using custom YAML

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

We are using C# rest API to create the pipeline for multi tenant application.

```
 string PipelineURL = string.Format("https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0",
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganizationName"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"].ToString());

var postData = new
            {
                folder = "",
                name = Name,
                configuration = new
                {
                    type = "yaml",
                    path= "/azure-pipelines.yml",
                    repository = new
                    {
                        id = "repo-id",
                        name = "repo-name",
                        type = "azureReposGit"
                    }
                }
            };
```

Using above Pipeline URL and input, able to create pipeline. But how can we pass custom YAML string as input instead of path.

Comment: What is your objective? YAML pipelines are based on YAML files within the repository. If you want the repo to contain different YAML, then you update the YAML in the repository. You don't update it through the pipeline definition.

Comment: @DanielMann This is multi tenant application, while we creating resource need to create pipeline. In this case need to update container name as well. So need to create pipeline with custom YAML string instead of Path

Comment: That's not how it works. All a YAML pipeline definition can do is point to a YAML file in a repository.

Comment: Do you need classic pipeline? This type of pipeline's definition will be in the JSON data in REST API. Please notice that YAML pipeline doesn't work via this way. YAML pipeline definition is based on the YAML in the repository. You can manually pass the custom string or auto pass a custom string. I provided a auto method based on C# code, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pipeline is based on YAML, then it must based on YAML file in repository, **there doesn't have a way to pass custom "YAML string" in REST API.**

## 1,

 If you want all pipeline definition be defined in JSON, you can create a classic pipeline via the REST API(You can manually create a classic pipeline first and then use [Pipelines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) REST API to check how to design it.).

## 2,

 If you want automatic method to pass custom string to yaml definition YAML, you can deserialize the YAML file to get the YAML content you want, change it via code, and then serialize the data and save back to the YAML file.

---

I notice you using C#, so I write a C# demo for you.

For example, I have a test YAML file like this:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- name: testkey
  value: testvalue
```

The below C# code will pass a custom string value to the value of testkey variable.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization.NamingConventions;

namespace change_YAML_content
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file_path = @"C:\repo\TestResults\change_YAML_content\test.yaml";
            string value_before_change = getvalue(file_path);
            setvalue(file_path);
            string value_after_change = getvalue(file_path);

            Console.WriteLine("The value before change: " + value_before_change + "\n" + "The value after change: " + value_after_change);
        }
        public static string getvalue(string file_path) 
        {
            var deserializer = new Deserializer();

            var reader = new StreamReader(file_path);
            var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize<YAMLFrontMeta>(reader);
            var variables = yamlObject.Variables;//This step you can make your own design.
            string rt = variables[0]["value"];
            reader.Close();
            return rt;
        }
        public static void setvalue(string file_path)
        {
            var deserializer = new Deserializer();
            var reader = new StreamReader(file_path);
            var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize<YAMLFrontMeta>(reader);
            var variables = yamlObject.Variables;//This step you can make your own design.
            variables[0]["value"] = "new value";

            //write the new content to YAML file
            var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
                .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
                .Build();
            var yaml = serializer.Serialize(yamlObject);

            reader.Close();
            File.WriteAllText(file_path, yaml);
        }
    }
    public sealed class YAMLFrontMeta
    {
        [YamlMember(Alias = "trigger", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
        public string Trigger { get; set; }

        [YamlMember(Alias = "pool", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
        public Dictionary<string, string> Pool { get; set; }

        [YamlMember(Alias = "variables", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
        public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Variables { get; set; }

        //... and so on
    }
}
```

After run the code, the YAML will be:

```
trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- name: testkey
  value: new value
```

The above a just a sample, if you need more complex use cases, you can design based on the above method, and you can even use this technique to automate the creation of the YAML files you want. After this you can push/upload the yaml file to the repository.

If you run the above code based on the repository where the YAML exists, then this will be helpful to you:

[Push changes back to repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123277/6261890)

## 3,

If you don't need automatic method to pass the custom string to YAML, then just edit the YAML in your repository is ok.