# Object as pipeline variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following pipeline variables:

```
---
variables:
  models:
    - name: model1
      image_name: image1
    - name: model2
      image_name: image2
```

However, this is not allowed: `A sequence was not expected`. It seems that pipeline variables can only be single line strings. Is there a clever way to work around this? I've read about [convertToJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops), but it's not desirable/readable to write the `models` variable in a single line json string.

For context, I'm passing this variable as a parameter to a template, where I will be looping over `parameters.models` and run a stage for each `model`, like this:

```
- ${{each model in parameters.models}}:
     - stage: {{ model.name }}
```

Apparently there is [a very old unresolved issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/multiple-lines-variable-in-build-and-release/365667) that could provide a solution... What would be the best workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DevOps YAML pipeline don't support such YAML structure:

```
variables:
  models:
    - name: model1
      image_name: image1
    - name: model2
      image_name: image2
```

The variables in DevOps pipeline concept is [only string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch).

And this place:

```
- ${{each model in parameters.models}}:
     - stage: {{ model.name }}
```

Here are two usages in DevOps YAML tech, were named [conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) and template expression.

Both of them need valid structure in DevOps YAML. Variables in DevOps YAML concept doesn't support such structure, so these usages are not possible.

A possible way is make your YAML pipeline like below:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
parameters:
- name: models
  type: object
  default:
  - name: model1
    image_name: image1
  - name: model2
    image_name: image2

stages:
  - ${{each model in parameters.models}}:
    - ${{ each modelcontent in model }}:
      - ${{ if eq(modelcontent.Key, 'name') }}:
        - stage: '${{ modelcontent.Value }}'
          jobs:
            - job:
              steps:
              - script: echo Hello, world!
                displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

Results:

[image]

Parameters can pass YAML object, and then use them in compile time usages. that's why I use parameters.

If you want handle the parameters automatically, the only way it to use another script/code/app to parse the YAML content getting from the repository and then change it. And after you finish the change, follow this to push back the changed YAML:

[Git push back changes to repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123277/6261890)

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that it is possible to pass complex structures through parameters and was thinking, as an alternative, about a script that reads a yaml config from my repo, so I'm glad you confirmed that as an ok alternative. Would be great to pass complex structures as variables in the future though. Or is there another reason why that's not implemented?

Comment: @DSteman Your requirement make sense. I suggest you to post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) and share your idea. I don't see any similar feature request there posted by other community members. DevOps product team plan their product timeline based on the user voices from that community. And you can check the DevOps feature timeline here: [DevOps RoadMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline).

Comment: Or update / vote the already in place https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/multiple-lines-variable-in-build-and-release/365667 like @DSteman mentioned in his original post

Comment: @promicro Thanks for your reply. But I think what DSteman means is to let the variables under the DevOps concept have the same degree of freedom as the DevOps parameters described in the document here: [Parameter data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameter-data-types) For this, I really did not find a related feature request. :)

Answer (score 1):

John Folberth almost does what you want, except he isn't passing it as a parameter to the yaml but to underlying templates:

https://blog.johnfolberth.com/advanced-azure-devops-yaml-objects/

The ConvertToJson is the other alternative, André van der Goes explains it in this blog post:

https://www.automagical.eu/posts/passing-complex-variables-devops-yaml/

Comment: These workarounds don't offer a solution to my issue, since they fix the parameter with a default value. That way I cannot pass `models` anymore from other pipelines that are using the template.

Comment: @DSteman ok, so how do you pass this from the other yamls at the moment?

Comment: I can't, that's the problem :p. You can only store strings as pipeline variables and pass those as parameters to a template. It's not possible to keep 'complex' structures as pipeline variables and pass those as parameters of a template, as suggested by @Bowman Zhu-MSFT.